# How to call Geowebcache tile openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, tiles

Can anyone provide the solution, how to call GeoWebCache tiles in openlayers as i have 20GB of tiles created in gwc folder.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  There seems to be considerable help already available at sites like http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/caching_data/using_gwc.html

Answer (score 2):

If Geoserver with GWC is running on your server, then it's as simple as using

```
http://example.com/geoserver/gwc/service/wms
```

instead of

```
http://example.com/geoserver/wms
```

for the WMS url in your JavaScript OpenLayers code. In other words, add `/gwc/service/wms` in between the path to your GeoServer instance and the WMS call

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is by setting the WMS request tiled propery to "true", without adding `/gwc/service/wms`

```
var layerX  = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("layerX", http://example.com/geoserver/wms?",{
//WMS parameters
layers : 'layerX',                                                                             
transparent : true,
format : 'image/png',
tiled : true // <-- Here
},
{
//Open Layer parameters
});
```

Comment: I disagree with you. The question is asking about "how to call GeoWebCache tiles in Open Layers". There are two ways of doing this: (1) Direct integration with GeoServer WMS - which is my option (2) GeoWebCache endpoint URL  - which is yours. For detailed explanation, please look at docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/using.html

Comment: I apologize; You were right, & my earlier understanding was wrong.